# JsRender with JsViews - views is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

I'm trying to implement a real basic sample of JsViews in a wizard,  have included  jquery.observable and jquery.views

But I get this error x-browser. "Views is null or not an object". The break occurs in jsRender, but I have other templating code working fine using jsRender, its only the inclusion of jquery.observable $ jquery.views. Does anyone have a jsfiddle of a simple binding example using jsRender / jsViews. No detail view needed, just the barest example of removing items from model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added 'remove' to the simple 'Observable Collection changes' example [here](http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/jQueryConfDemosOct2011/07_observable2.html). (Code is [here](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/blob/master/demos/jQueryConfDemosOct2011/07_observable2.html)).

Comment: Awesome Boris, that's what I was after :)

Comment: Great - glad it gave you answer to your issue!